# Land cover classification of different acquisition dates

Tags: classification, mosaic

I am doing a land cover classification of a large area, therefore all the images over the area do not all have the same acquisition dates. This results in my output having visible borders:

[image]

The images appear slightly different (one has more vegetation and the other less). How can I solve this issue? Is there a method to adjust the images to one another so the classification is smoother?